# I am unable to drop specific values in a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas data frame which I made using an text file in Python. I was able to read the data and made the dataframe but after some processing, I am having many redundant values in my dataframe and I want to remove the repeated values.
I tried using

```
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['FROM', 'ATTENDANCE'], keep = 'last', inplace=False)
df2
```

[image]

but still, the repeated data is there and is not removed. I tried everything with drop_duplicates() and nothing of them worked for me.

Comment: look for trailing spaces?

Comment: what do you mean? how should I do that?

Comment: for example, in the picture above, rows `1` and `2` appear to be duplicated. But row `1` may be `' Usha Dubey'` while row `2` is `'Usha Dubey'`. Maybe `df1['FROM'] = df1['FROM'].str.strip()` before drop duplicate will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really appreciated. But can you help more with this, I am still unable to do that.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UbAz6p4TcWEuMPBSxVKL1XWM2eEqNE_d


this is my colab notebook can you please take a look and resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your colab, `df1` is a copy of another `df`, so you can't really change the values of it's columns. You should do:

```
df1 = df[['FROM', 'ATTENDANCE']].copy()
df1['FROM'] = df1['FROM'].str.strip()

df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

Output:

```
                  FROM ATTENDANCE
2           Usha Dubey    PRESENT
9   Pranjal Srivastava    PRESENT
11       Jagriti Gupta    PRESENT
12         Samaksh X A    PRESENT
13        Bhavya Malik    PRESENT
```